# Find last row > merge cells > copy and paste into it - Excel VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have no experience with VBA and it's proving to be more difficult than what I imagined...in part because I don't know the syntax, but I have the following:

```
Sub testMe()

  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

  Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow)

End Sub
```

This kinda works, but it's jamming everything into one cell in the first column. How do I merge the cells of the last row before pasting into it? The macro is supposed to find the last row of the last page, merge the cells of that row, and paste text that was copied from another cell. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suggest that you use the macro recorder to manually accomplish the merging that you want to perform, then look at the code it produced.  That will give you a start on "how to merge cells".  You may want to use End + Right Arrow as you record, especially if you need to select as many cells as there are to the right in that last row, without knowing in advance the particular number of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this...

```
Sub testMe()

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Range("A" & LastRow & ":L" & LastRow).Merge
Range("A" & LastRow) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after. You should just change the column number to reflect the column which you wish to merge cells until.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copy_and_paste_merge()
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Cells(1, 1).Copy
    Cells(last_row, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range(Cells(last_row, 1), Cells(last_row, 5)).MergeCells = True 'change the column
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, but getting the error message: `to do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size`. And I don't see the line in your code where my text is being copied from the A1 cell on sheet 2. Thank you though, for trying to help me...I really do appreciate it.